# jasperreports-maven-plugin - How do I set the JDK version?

Tags: intellij-idea, jasper-reports, maven-plugin

I am installing my maven project using *IntelliJ IDEA*. I have set the *Java* compiler to ***1.6*** in IDE settings, but it seems *jasperreports-maven-plugin* is using ***1.7***. I am 99% sure it is because my system *`JAVA_HOME`* is set to ***1.7***.

As a result, I get the following error when installing:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: demo1_1377077829323_970805 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

How do I get *jasperreports-maven-plugin* to use *JDK 1.6*, and not the system *`JAVA_HOME`*?

Comment: Did you set the *JRE* at *Maven->Runner* options dialog?

Comment: Yes, it is set to 'Use project JDK' which is also 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this fix http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-809

```
<configuration>
  <javaDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-jasper</javaDirectory>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-jasper/cd/Reports</outputDirectory>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/jrxml</sourceDirectory>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler</compiler>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Codehaus is dead, long live Codehaus.  Problem is that I can't see that link anymore, and I feel like I need to.  Is this configuration in the executions.execution.configuration or the plugin.configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this, I'm running Ubuntu and had recently installed java 7.

I solved this problem by setting the default java version and javac version with the following commands... just select the version you require when prompted.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

hope that helps someone

Comment: Thank you Robert. I was hoping not to have to change the defaults, though. But thanks for the advice, much appreciated.